# CSS Grid Layout - Como centralizar horizontalmente todos os elementos em todas as Grid Lines de uma Sub-Grid?

Tags: css, css3, layout-responsivo, grid-layout

Estou trabalhando em um projeto de faculdade e estamos utilizando Grid Layout para fazer o design de um e-commerce voltado para animais. Surgiu uma duvida durante o processo de criação em relação à centralização do conteúdo das grids em diferentes resoluções e tipos de dispositivos.

O código CSS simplificado é:

```
#produtos-grid {
    grid-area: grid-produtos;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:    "produtos-destaque-titulo"
                            "produtos-destaque"
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

#produtos-destaque-titulo-grid {
    grid-area: produtos-destaque-titulo;
}

#produtos-destaque-grid {
    grid-area: produtos-destaque;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(225px, 350px));
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    grid-row-gap: 1em;
}
```

Ainda não estamos adicionando os itens diretamente do banco de dados com o php porque o projeto está bem no começo nesse ponto e não tivemos tempo de modelar tudo, por isso a info foi colocada diretamente no HTML para testar o posicionamento dos elementos na view. Novamente, o código resumido é:

```
<main class="container" id="produtos-grid">     

      <div id="produtos-destaque-titulo-grid">
        <h5 class="text-center">Mais Vendidos</h5>
        <hr>
      </div>

      <div id="produtos-destaque-grid">

        <div class="card bordered">
          <div>
            <a href="<?=base_url()?>/index.php/produto/visualizar/17">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="<?=base_url()?>/assets/imagens/produtos/cama-suiça-bege-bichinho-chic.jpg" alt="Imagem Produto">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-text">Cama Suiça Bege Bichinho Chic</h5>
            <p class="card-text">a partir de: R$ 51,90</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card bordered">
          <div>
            <a href="<?=base_url()?>index.php/produto/visualizar/1">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="<?=base_url()?>/assets/imagens/produtos/racao-whiskas-gatos-castrados-carne.jpg" alt="Imagem Produto">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-text">Ração Whiskas Gatos Castrados Carne</h5>
            <p class="card-text">a partir de: R$ 11,99</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card bordered">
          <div>
            <a href="<?=base_url()?>index.php/produto/visualizar/5">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="<?=base_url()?>/assets/imagens/produtos/brinquedo-cenoura-nylon-buddy-toys.jpg" alt="Imagem Produto">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-text">Brinquedo Cenoura Nylon Buddy Toys</h5>
            <p class="card-text">a partir de: R$ 37,90</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>  

</main>
```

O código gera o seguinte resultado quando a propriedade width do display está igual ou acima de 1200px:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando a resolução está abaixo de 1200px, uma das imagens é jogada diretamente para a posição abaixo das outras (2º Grid Line), o que é exatamente o que queremos. O problema é que a imagem deveria estar **Centralizada** no meio das outras duas, e não à esquerda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual solução pode ser utilizada para centralizar todos os items da grid horizontalmente, independente da Grid Line em que se encontram?

Comment: Jovem se vc colocar o HTML ajuda... Só com CSS complica te dar uma resposta precisa... Principalmente pe vc está usando "grid-template-areas" como vamos saber a estrutura do html, fica complicado

Comment: Atualizado, por algum motivo esqueci de colocar o HTML e só adicionei o CSS. O resto do HTML é estruturado similar ao acima, existe uma grid para produtos de cães, gatos, medicamentos e outros.

Comment: Já tentou dar um "margin: 0 auto;" no produto?

Comment: @DiegoSantos Foi a primeira solução que tentei, antes de saber que existia o Justify-Content, e lembro que não funcionou. Sinceramente, não me lembro o porquê exatamente de não ter funcionado, só lembro que deu muito errado

Comment: Qual o css do "card bordered"?

Comment: É a classe Card do Bootstrap 4 com uma borda simples ao redor. Uso o bootstrap 4 só no Banner e nas cards, tô até pensando em retirar e fazer na mão depois quando tiver um tempo livre pra eliminar a dependência

Comment: Cara se vc está usando Bootstrap 4 vc deveria usar o FlexBox que é nativo do BS4 e resolve isso fácil

Comment: @hugocsl como disse acima, estou exatamente no processo de retirar o bootstrap 4, e não planejo utilizar ele em projetos futuros, por isso quero entender como fazer isso sem utilizar o flexbox do bootstrap.

Comment: Apenas com Grid e CSS vc não vai conseguir. Talvez com algum JavaScript resolva, mas só com Grid acho que não dá, por isso sugeri o FlexBox, que mesmo sendo usado pelo BS4 também é amplamente usado na web sem demais problemas.

Comment: Entendo, imaginava que existia uma solução para o problema utilizando somente o Grid. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) sempre vai quebrar a row e colocar os itens em ordem de coluna.

Neste caso recomendo o uso de [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) que faz exatamente o que quer com a propriedade `justify-content: center`